# 3D Vector transformations - when to use w = 1

Tags: matrix, c++11

I'm writing some code that transforms vectors with matrices in D3DX9. When is the correct time to use w=0 and w=1? The MSDN documentation is not terribly helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the vector is representing a **direction** (e.g. a vertex normal) **w should be zero**, If the vector is representing a **point** in 3d space (e.g. location of a vertex) then **w = 1**.